# Seeking some easier method to prove the identity

Tags: discrete-mathematics, summation, induction, solution-verification, symmetric-polynomials

I came across the identity

> Let $n$ and $m$ be natural numbers and $p_{1}, p_{2}, p_{3}...p_{n}$ be real numbers. Prove that if any $a_{1},a_{2},..a_{k}$ for any $ k\le n$ ramdomly chosen from the set $S$ = {$p_{1}, p_{2}, p_{3}...p_{n}$} follow $$ \prod_{i=1}^{k} a_{i} = \sum_{i = 1}^{k}a_{i}-k+1$$ then  $$(\prod_{i=1}^{n} p_{i})^{m} =  (\sum_{i = 1}^{n}p_{i}-n+1)^{m} = \sum_{i=1}^{n}p_{i}^{m}-n+1 $$

**MY TRY :-** For e.g. for $n=2$ we have $pq=p+q-1$ and we need to prove that $(p+q-1)^{m} = p^{m}+q^{m}-1$ but as pointed out by Wolfgang Kais it is fairly simple as the equation $p+q-1 = pq$ is satisfied if and only if $(p-1)(q-1) = 0\implies$ either $p=1$ or $q=1$ which then is simple to prove.

I also proved it for any n using induction. I have written the method in answer. But it took a large calculation to do it. I suppose there will definitely be some easier method to prove it.
Any help will be highly appreciated.
Please ask for clarifications in case of discrepencies.

Comment: Btw: The case $n=2$ is true, but it's quite boring, because $pq=p+q-1$ can only be true if either $p=1$ or $q=1$ (or both), so it reduces to the trivial case $n=1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Knowing the prerequisit that was previously missing, the proof can indeed be simplified. To be more specific, we can conclude that all but at most one of the numbers are equal to $1$. We can use the case $n=2$ to do so.

For $n=1$, we can choose any real number $p_1$ and trivially at most one of this one number differs from $1$.

Now, let $n\ge2$ be an integer and $p_1,...,p_n$ be real numbers such that for any integer $k \le n$ and any $k$-subset $\{j_1, ..., j_k\} \subseteq \{1,...,n\}$ we have
$$
\prod_{i=1}^k p_{j_i}=\sum_{i=1}^k p_{j_i}-(k-1)
$$
Then, for any pair $(i,j)$ with $i,j \in \{1,...,n\}$, $i \ne j$, we have
$$\begin{align}
p_i \cdot p_j &= p_i+p_j-(2-1)\\
\Leftrightarrow 1-p_i-p_j+p_i\cdot p_j&=0\\
\Leftrightarrow (1-p_i)\cdot (1-p_j)&=0\\
\Leftrightarrow p_i=1 \lor p_j=1&
\end{align}$$
Therefore, at least one member of every pair of the numbers is equal to $1$. This can only be true if at most one of the numbers differs from $1$. So, all but at most one of the numbers are equal to $1$. W.l.o.g, we assume that $p_1=...=p_{n-1}=1$ and we conclude for any integer $m \ge 1$:
$$
(\prod_{i=1}^n p_i)^m=p_n^m = p_n^m+\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}1^m-(n-1)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}p_i^m-(n-1)
$$

Comment: It seems there is a gap in your argument. How did you prove that at most one of the numbers differs from 1.

Comment: @Spartan Assume that two of the numbers differ from $1$, name them $p$ and $q$ and apply your newly added restriction to the subset with just these two numbers: $$pq=p+q-1 \Leftrightarrow (p-1)(q-1)=0$$ If follows that at least one of them must be $1$ which is a contradiction.

Comment: Great! this simplifies the problem to a large extent.

Answer (score 0):

We'll use strong form of induction on $m$, let $n$ be arbitrary, base case $m = 1$ is trivial, let   $$ \Bigl(\sum_{i=1}^{n}p_{i}-n+1\Bigr)^{m} = \sum_{i=1}^{n}p_{i}^{m}-n+1    \space \forall\space 2\le m\leq k$$ we'll prove that it also holds for $m = k+1$. Let $n-1 = t$ to reduce the congestion.

$$\biggl(\sum_{i=1}^{n}p_{i}-t\biggr)^{k+1} = \biggl(\sum_{j=1}^{n}p_{j}-t\biggr)^{k}\biggl(\sum_{i=1}^{n}p_{i}-t\biggr) = \biggl(\sum_{j=1}^{n}p_{j}^{k}-t\biggr)\biggl(\sum_{i=1}^{n}p_{i}-t\biggr)$$ $$   
 = \sum_{i=1}^{n}-t(p_{i}+p_{i}^{k})+t^{2}+\sum_{j=1}^{n}p_{j}^{k}\sum_{i=1}^{n}p_{i}$$Call the above equation [$1$]. The last term in [$1$]$$\sum_{j=1}^{n}p_{j}^{k}\sum_{i=1}^{n}p_{i} = \sum_{j=1}^{n}p_{j}^{k}\sum_{i\neq j}^{n}p_{i}+ \sum_{j=1}^{n}p_{j}^{k+1} = \sum_{j=1}^{n}p_{j}^{k}\biggl(\prod_{i\neq j}^{n}p_{i}+n-2\biggr)+\sum_{j=1}^{n}p_{j}^{k+1}$$
$$= \sum_{j=1}^{n}p_{j}^{k-1}\prod_{i=1}^{n}p_{i}+(n-2)\sum_{j=1}^{n}p_{j}^{k}+\sum_{j=1}^{n}p_{j}^{k+1}$$
Call this equation [$2$]. First term in [2]$$\sum_{j=1}^{n}p_{j}^{k-1}\prod_{i=1}^{n}p_{i}=\prod_{i=1}^{n}p_{i}\biggl[\sum_{j=1}^{n}p_{j}^{k-1}-t\biggr]+t\prod_{i=1}^{n}p_{i}$$
$$=\prod_{i=1}^{n}p_{i}\biggl(\sum_{j=1}^{n}p_{j}-t\biggr)^{k-1}+t\prod_{i=1}^{n}p_{i}=\biggl(\sum_{j=1}^{n}p_{j}-t\biggr)^{k}+t\prod_{i=1}^{n}p_{i}$$
Coming back to [$1$] RHS
$$ = -t\sum_{i=1}^{n}p_{i}-t\sum_{i=1}^{n}p_{i}^{k}+t^{2}+\Biggl(\biggl(\sum_{j=1}^{n}p_{j}-t\biggr)^{k}+t\prod_{i=1}^{n}p_{i}+(t-1)\sum_{j=1}^{n}p_{j}^{k}+\sum_{j=1}^{n}p_{j}^{k+1}\Biggr)$$
Arranging the terms $$ =\sum_{j=1}^{n}p_{j}^{k+1}-t\Bigl(\sum_{i=1}^{n}p_{i}-\prod_{i=1}^{n}p_{i}\Bigr)+t^2-\sum_{j=1}^{n}p_{j}^{k} +\biggl(\sum_{j=1}^{n}p_{j}-t\biggr)^{k}$$
$$ =\sum_{j=1}^{n}p_{j}^{k+1}-t\Bigl(t\Bigr)+t^2-\sum_{j=1}^{n}p_{j}^{k} +\Bigl(\sum_{j=1}^{n}p_{j}^{k}-t\Bigr) = \sum_{j=1}^{n}p_{j}^{k+1}-t.$$

Comment: In your proof, you seem to use the fact that (for $j=1...n$):
$$
\sum_{i \ne j}^n p_i=\prod_{i \ne j}^n p_i+(n-2)
$$
Ths can only be assumed if $p_j=1$, otherwise we have
$$
\sum_{i \ne j}^n p_i=p_j\prod_{i \ne j}^n p_i+(n-1)-p_j
$$

Comment: @WolfgangKais I had further a restriction on the numbers $p_{1},p_{2}..p_{n}$ that the product of any number of terms = sum of those terms - (number of terms)+$1$. On those lines the fact is true. I have edited the problem further.

Comment: Well, that was indeed a quite important information. I will add a new answer and remove my previous one, because knowing that missing fact there is indeed a very simple proof.